# Combining two observables in F#

Tags: f#, observable

I'm having trouble understanding how to manage multiple observables that depend on each other. I want to define a function with the following signature:

```
    clock:IObservable<unit> -> obs:IObservable<'a> -> IObservable<'a>
```

So that events from obs can only be emitted once per clock tick, and excess events from obs are discarded.

I have tried mapping the two observables and then merging them into one stream, but it is not the solution.

Comment: I don't think it's easy to do just with F#'s built-in `Observable` support, but have a look at `Observable.WithLatestFrom()` in Reactive Extensions. (For a more F# friendly API to that, have a look at the NuGet package `FSharp.Control.Reactive`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in F# library for Observables comes with only a few basic functions, so this is not something you can easily do using the built-in primitives. You can probably use a function from the full Rx library, which has a nice [F# wrapper](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive) and comes with huge number of operations (but that makes it a bit hard to figure out which one is the one that you need).

An alternative purely F# approach would be to use agent-based programming. This lets you nicely handle complex concurrency patterns. The following implements an agent that has `Tick` and `Event` as two kinds of messages. It remembers the last `Event` and when `Tick` happens, it trigges the returned observable with the last `Event` value:

```
open System

type WhenTickMessage<'T> = 
  | Tick
  | Event of 'T

let whenTick (clock:IObservable<_>) (event:IObservable<_>) = 
  let result = new Event<_>()
  let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop event = async {
      let! msg = inbox.Receive()
      match msg with 
      | Tick -> 
          event |> Option.iter (fun e -> result.Trigger(e))
          return! loop None
      | Event e ->
          return! loop (Some e) }
    loop None)
  clock.Add(fun _ -> agent.Post Tick)
  event.Add(fun e -> agent.Post (Event e))
  result.Publish
```